# How to handle the errors in Selenium Webdriver Node Js. NoSuchElementError

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

When I run the test, sometimes I got the the following error:

"(node:34959) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:..."

And the test stops.

I want the test to going on and not to stop, but write a message into console.

My code now:

```
var one = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='somethig']/following-sibling::td[1]/strong"));
var two = await one.getText();
await fs.appendFileSync("file.txt", two + ",");
```

How is it possible? Because I don't need this element, for further run.
Thanks :)

Comment: It is not the same question man... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only just need to wrap the error you need to log to console in `try` and `catch`.

```
let one = '';
let two = '';
try {
    one = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='somethig']/following-sibling::td[1]/strong"));
    two = await one.getText();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
await fs.appendFileSync("file.txt", two + ",");
```

Comment: Thank you. It is nearly good. Just I cant take into a function, because I always get "object promise". :/ But it will be a new question. :)